# accessing Desktop from Root directory

Tags: linux, terminal

I was using aircrack-ng package in my ubuntu 15.04. This package works only under root privileges. Now I want to save **.cap file** on my desktop using airodump-ng package but everytime I do, it throws an error

```
-bash: cd: Desktop/: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know how can I access Desktop from my root directory.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask. You probably want to ask your question on the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or the [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) communities.

Comment: @Yuriko - thanx for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> cd /home/{your username}/Desktop

It will always take you to your desktop folder if you have access permissions.

Comment: If you are currently logged in as the user you will be using - You will also be able to cd ~/Desktop - ~ being the shortcut for /home/{Your username}